# Boolean field inside node twig renders ok but does not work in if statement

Tags: theming, nodes, 8, entities

I have an node twig and I want to use field of that node inside if of that twig. I managed to get the boolean value via `content.field_sample|raw`. But it looks like it doesn't work in `if` statement. For give code:

```
Value: {{ content.field_sample|raw }}
{% if content.field_sample|raw == '1' %}
    OK
{% else %}
    Error
{% endif %}
```

I get output:

```
Value: 1
Error
```

Sames goes for `{% if content.field_sample|raw == 1 %}`.

`{% if content.field_sample|raw == true %}` always returns true, regardless the boolean is on or off (it returns true for both `Value: 0` and `Value: 1`). I guess it's  because it just checks if fields exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In content is the render array of the field output. A boolean is probably a text in `#markup`. What text this is for 0/1 can be configured in the display mode. But don't try to find it there, better use for coding the node. There you get the values directly from the database.

```
{% if node.field_sample.value %}
```

Comment: Thank you, `node...value` instead of `content.` was the clean way to go :)